# uploadify s3 404

Tags: php, amazon-s3, uploadify

I have made use of the jQuery uploadify example with Amazon S3 and seem to be getting an error 404. Where is this error coming from...

In the example it states that all you need to do is change the details and obviously replace it with your credentials, (AWS key, AWS Secret and bucket name) which has been done, but for some reason I still get an error.

Does anybody have a working php s3 uploadify example, or know of an alternate way in doing this???

I have looked and based most info from here

http://www.uploadify.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=4713

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chose to go with SWFUpload instead, way more stable solution!